# dojo1.8 - populate dijit/select with data from mysql

Tags: dojo

Hi how do I populate the records from gathertests.php into dijit/select?
I do not think that I should use innerHTML as that would build not the dijit/select. Maybe I should use the function. But how?

```
request.post('gathertests.php',{
    data:{testx : selectX.value},
}).then
    {
    function(response){   dom.byId('line4').innerHTML=response;                         
},
function(error){
    alert(error);
});
```

Please advise 
Thanks
Clement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create [`dojo/store/Memory`](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/store/Memory.html) or ideally [`dojo/store/JsonRest`](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/store/JsonRest.html) and assign the store to the `dijit/Select`.

Do not manipulate the DOM directly, mutate data in `dojo/store` (i.e. the model), dijits observe it and update the DOM accordingly.

Please see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12782976/dojo-declarative-vs-programmatic-creation-of-select-elements-with-stores/12783555#12783555) to *Dojo declarative vs. programmatic creation of Select elements with stores* and the related [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/phusick/ZmsYV/).

**Bonus**: a bit more complex example: http://jsfiddle.net/phusick/N8DqG/